# Button goes out of its div when screen size becomes smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I am trying to build a todo list, there's an edit button whose size is equal to the div height at normal or larger screens, but when the screen becomes smaller than 500px, button collapses and goes out of the its div,
Here how my list looks in medium and larger screens [image]

but when i resize my window to less than 400 or 500px, it looks like

[image: image2]

here's my react JSX code

```
export default function TodoList(props) {
     const list = props.todos.map(todo =>
          <div className="TodoList">
               <h3 >{todo.todo}</h3>
               <div className="btn">
               <button>edit</button>
               </div>
               
          </div>
          
     )
     return (
          <div>
               {list}
          </div>
     )
}
```

and my css looks like

```
.TodoList{
     background: #283048;  /* fallback for old browsers */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
     padding: 2px;
     margin: 10px;     
     display: block;
     width: 50%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     color: snow;
     transform: skew(20deg);
     height: 3rem;
     
}

.TodoList h3{
     transform: skew(-20deg);
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     display: inline-block;
}

.btn{
     float: right;
     height: 100%;
}

.btn button{
     height: 100%
}
```

Comment: There is not enough room, so it will overflow, what is it you would rather it do.?

Comment: I just want to make the button occupy equivalent height to its div, I want the div and button to take as much height as required to display the same markup as on medium and larger screens.

Comment: Remove the height, div''s as default grow to there contents, by giving it a height your overriding that, and overflows will happen.  Also rather than floats, display of type flex might be better for that sort of layout.

Comment: by removing height on div, my button is not taking equivalent height to its div

Comment: That's why I also suggested display flex, the button height would also update, it can be done without, but it's much easier with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly was on mobile while making comments, so making a snippet would have been awkward.

So here is an example of using FlexBox,  if you look it also makes the markup simpler too.  It's this sort of layout that flexbox is very useful for.  No need for height 100% etc, or wrapper div's.

```css
.TodoList{
     background: #283048;  /* fallback for old browsers */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
     padding: 2px;
     margin: 10px;     
     display: flex;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     color: snow;
     transform: skew(20deg);
     text-align: center;
}

.TodoList h3{
     flex: 1;
     transform: skew(-20deg);
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     display: inline-block;
}

.TodoList {
     width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="TodoList">
     <h3 >Make Coffee</h3>
     <button>edit</button>
</div>
<div class="TodoList">
     <h3 >Make Tea</h3>
     <button>edit</button>
</div>
<div class="TodoList">
     <h3 >Make Orange Juice</h3>
     <button>edit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, and works perfectly too, with comparatively less markup. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually in your CSS. When the screen becomes smaller no room is left for the todolist and button in skew 20 degrees. If you remove the `width: 50%;` rule and use `text-align: center;`  you will get a perfect result.

```css
.TodoList{
     background: #283048;  /* fallback for old browsers */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #859398, #283048); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
     padding: 2px;
     margin: 10px;     
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     color: snow;
     transform: skew(20deg);
     height: 3rem;
     text-align: center;
}

.TodoList h3{
     transform: skew(-20deg);
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     display: inline-block;
}

.btn{
     float: right;
     height: 100%;
}

.btn button{
     height: 100%
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .TodoList {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="TodoList">
     <h3 >Make Coffee</h3>
     <div class="btn">
     <button>edit</button>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="TodoList">
     <h3 >Make Tea</h3>
     <div class="btn">
     <button>edit</button>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="TodoList">
     <h3 >Make Orange Juice</h3>
     <div class="btn">
     <button>edit</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by doing so, my todo is taking all the width of the screen which looks soo odd.

Comment: Then you should limit the width depending on media queries [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: please look at the updated answer after using the CSS media query

Comment: Thanks, I have found a solution by using position property with your media query, now its working perfect.The problem with your solution is that the height is hard-coded due to which larger todos overflow and messed up

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found a better solution. now my button is taking equivalent height to its div at every screen size, and my div height is increasing according to its content. I have updated the .btn class with position property which sync's my button height with that of div.

```
.btn{
     float: right;
     position:absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
}
```

and added a margin for not hiding text beneath the button

```
.TodoList h3{
     transform: skew(-20deg);
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     display: inline-block;
     /* margin is added to shift text onto new line instead of hiding it beneath the edit button */
     margin: 5px 25px;
}
```

and added a media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
     .TodoList {
       width: 50%;
     }
}
```

here's how it looks now
[image]

Comment: Your padding of 2px is now gone, is this what your after.  Also your text is now not centred.

Comment: yeah, I refactored the code . My real problem was the button height and now I have figured out, everything else is just a matter of choice for me

Comment: Ok,. No problem.  Just remember position absolute takes it out of render flow, and is the reason your text is now not centred.   And depending on screen size, or text length, the text might now render into your button.